# Weighted-Graph Datasets

Tags: graphs, machine-learning, reference-request, data-sets

I am searching for datasets to evaluate an algorithm designed for tasks such as node-classification (edge-prediction, etc.) on *weighted* and potentially directed graphs.

The [Stanford Network Analysis Project (SNAP)](http://snap.stanford.edu/) repository only contains datasets containing *temporal* weighted graphs.

Are there standard datasets for such tasks on non-temporal weighted (and directed) graphs?

Answer (score 2):

I think these datasets meet your constraints, [wn18rr](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/wn18rr) and [proteins](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/proteins). I found them by looking [here](https://paperswithcode.com/datasets?mod=graphs).